# KeyPress Event for textbox which is in gridview

Tags: asp.net

i have a gridview in that 
  
 
   
 '>
                                                                        <%--    onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);" --%>

if i press enter key in this focus must go to second row same column's textbox....

Hope u understand my question

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use

```
    if(event.keyCode == 13)
            moveToNextElement(event.target);

    function moveToNextElement(target) {
            //you have the current location target as reference
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assmuing you have a text box in each row of a gridview, and you want to focus the next textbox in the same column on the row below on enter on a particaular textbox.

```
    protected void GridView1_OnDataBound(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index <= GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; index++) {
        dynamic CurrentTextBox = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows(index).FindControl("yourTextBoxId");
        //Set Focus to Next TextBox 
        if ((index != GridView1.Rows.Count - 1)) {
            dynamic NextTextBox = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows(index + 1).FindControl("yourTextBoxId");
            CurrentTextBox.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "setFocus('" + NextTextBox.ClientID + "');");
        }
        }
    }
```

Write the following javascript function in your aspx page.

```
    function setFocus(Target)
    {
        if(window.event.keyCode=="13")
        document.getElementById(Target).focus();  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply but i am working on .Net2.0 so i dont't have this namespace

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But In place of Dynamic use TextBox.